# Equality of functions

Tags: functions

How a function which is not defined for some value can be equal to a function which is defined for the same value? How is $f(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-2)(x-4)}$ equal to $g(x) = \frac{(x-3)}{(x-4)}$ when their domains are different?

Comment: I would agree that they are not equal.  Although they are equal at any value where they are both defined.

Comment: You need to be precise what you mean. In some contexts they are equal in other contexts they are not equal. Sometimes people also are just sloppy.

Comment: When I put them into wolfram alpha to test for equality it says that they are equal. Also, I know that simplifying yields to an equivalent fraction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual problem is that what you wrote there are not the *functions*, but just two terms varying by a certain parameter.

In order to call those a function, you have to define the *domain*, which would look like this:

$$f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{2, 4\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x) := \frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-2)(x-4)}\\
g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto g(x) := \frac{(x-3)}{(x-4)}\\$$
Now, $f\ne g$, but it equals the *restriction* of g to the domain of f: $f = g|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \{2, 4\}}$

EDIT: Let me explain a bit more about how to compare terms and functions regarding equality.

- **Functions** are defined as relations with certain properties (uniqueness & definedness of the argument):
  $f: A\rightarrow B, x\mapsto f(x) :\Leftrightarrow f := \{(x, y)\in A\times B|y = f(x)\}$, which has to hold $\forall x\in A\exists!y\in B: (x, y)\in f$ as the defining property of a function.
- If two functions are **equal** is therefore just a question of comparing two *sets*. It holds if both contain exactly the same elements $(x, f(x))$. Thus, they must have the *same domain*.
- When comparing two **expressions** regarding equality, one has to be careful as well: Let $f(x), g(x)$ be expressions. $f(x) = g(x)$ would not be a logical statement, because We do not know what x is — therefore, we have to give an explicit x or quantorize it: $$\forall x: f(x) = g(x)$$ Because a quantorization without limiting x to a certain set (let's say $\mathbb{R}$) would only make sense if we would concern f(x) = g(x) = x, which would allow x to be something else than a number, you have to give a domain in some way *as well*.
  For instance, let $f(x) := \frac{x-1}{x-1}, g(x) := 1$: $\forall x\in M: f(x)=g(x)$ would hold true for M = $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, but not for $\mathbb{R}$, because there is no $f(x)$ at $x=1$.

Comment: What do I need in order to compare the two functions? I mean which things(domain,codomain, etc)

Comment: What do you mean by _compare_?

Comment: To compare for equality.

Comment: Well, a function is actually just a _relation_ (a set of 2-tuples) with certain properties, more explicitly $f = \{x, f(x)\}$, which makes it just the comparison of two _sets_.

Comment: The domain of the first function is R/{2}. When we do transformations on the first function to get the second we are dividing by (x-2) and "define" a new function g(x) equal to the previous but we restrict it's domain to R/{2}? Because if we let the domain to be R then they are not equal functions? Am I right?

Comment: That's the right thought, although it is not a “transformation” onto the function — you are just manipulating the underlying term. But you are right.

Comment: I have one more question. Why is f(x) = (x-1)/(x-1) equal to f(x) = 1?

Comment: Because you divide by $x-1$…?
Again, do you concern _functions_ or _terms_? This question rather confuses me.

Comment: I think it's the same if you consider them like functions or rational expressions. When you divide by x-1 you restrict the domain of f(x). Does that mean you must restrict the domain of g(x) = 1 to R/{1} to consider them equal?

Comment: Yes. In this case, $f \cup \{1, 1\} = g$ or $f = g|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}}$

Comment: I extended my answer, I hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

They are not. You can only say they assume the same values in the intersection of their domains, that is: $$f|_{D(f) \cap D(g)} = g|_{D(f) \cap D(g)}.$$

---

This answer assumes the definition: two functions $f:A \to B$ and $g:C \to D$ are equal if: $A = C$, $B = D$ and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in A = C$.

Comment: What is $D(f)$?

Comment: Here I meant the domain of $f$. Could be ${\rm dom} (f)$, too :)

Comment: How is that defined?

Comment: The Domain of f. For $f: A\rightarrow B$, $D(f) = A$.

Comment: Lukas beat me to it. That's it.

Comment: @LukasJuhrich so we take $A = [10,20]$ for $f$ and $g$ and the answer is false?

Comment: The problem is that OP didn't specify the exact domains in the problem. So we just assume that it's the largest domain possible for each function. I added in my answer the definition of equality of functions I'm assuming.

Comment: I think you really meant to require $A=C$ and $B=D$, not $A=B$ and $C=D$. But still, +1 for this answer. The answer accepted by the OP is not completely correct as it omits the requirement that the ranges (a.k.a. codomains) also be equal. This is a technically important although frequently forgotten requirement. Excellent!

Comment: Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The reason we can't check functions for equality is because:
 1. It reduces to The Halting Problem
 2. Functions tend to have an infinite set of inputs, and as others have mentioned, checking functions for equality is a question of comparing two sets.

But we could try to force both expressions to have the same format, then check symbol by symbol, I suppose.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's true that equality of functions is not generally decidable, but I don't see how that's related to the question.